# Mongo 'find' method does not work for DateTime.MinValue

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, gridfs

I am writing some *date* fields as metadata to GridFS using the Mongo 2.2.3.3 C# driver. Corner case is `DateTime.MinValue`. This gets represented as `Date(-62135596800000)`, which represents the number of milliseconds since January 1st 1970 ([mongo doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Date/)), which would be `new DateTime(1970,1,1).AddMilliseconds(-62135596800000)` in C# syntax. All good so far.

When querying for distinct date values  `db.fs.files.distinct("metadata.lastWriteTimeUtc")`, I get the value above and a series of ISODates in the `ISODate("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ")`format. However when trying to query for the corner case...

Checking for equality(none below) does not work:

```
db.fs.files.find({"metadata.lastWriteTimeUtc": Date(-62135596800000)})
db.fs.files.find({"metadata.lastWriteTimeUtc": Date("0001-01-01T00:00:00")  })
db.fs.files.find({"metadata.lastWriteTimeUtc": Date("0001-01-01T00:00:00")  })
db.fs.files.find({"metadata.lastWriteTimeUtc": ISODate("0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z")  })
db.fs.files.find({"metadata.lastWriteTimeUtc": ISODate("0001-01-01T00:00:00Z")  })
db.fs.files.find({"metadata.lastWriteTimeUtc": ISODate("0001-01-01")  })
```

Comparing to another value does not work with the date constructor

```
db.fs.files.find({"metadata.lastWriteTimeUtc": {$lt: Date(0)}  })
```

yet it does with the ISODate one

```
db.fs.files.find({"metadata.lastWriteTimeUtc": {$lt: ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z")}  })
```

The comparison approach is a workaround and I don't like it. Anyone aware why the `distinct` method finds `DateTime.MinValue` and `find` does not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add `new`

```
db.fs.files.find({"metadata.lastWriteTimeUtc": new Date(-62135596800000)})
db.fs.files.find({"metadata.lastWriteTimeUtc": new Date(0)})
db.fs.files.find({"metadata.lastWriteTimeUtc": new Date("0001-01-01T00:00:00")  })
```